# What is the right way to start DotNetNuke project in visual studio?

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2015, dotnetnuke

there was a couple of days that I arguing about first step to start DotNetNuke in Visual Studio correctly,

I downloaded DotNetNuke from [here](https://codeload.github.com/dnnsoftware/Dnn.Platform/zip/development) then I unzipped whole file and opened up the website project (I mean [this](https://github.com/dnnsoftware/Dnn.Platform/blob/development/Website/DotNetNuke.Website.csproj) file) but I got an error which complaining about:

> This project references NuGet package(s) that are missing on this computer

after a little search finally I figured it out that I must copy `.nuget` folder in the web folder, but it's just getting worst:( , below is the screenshot of the errors

[image: Errors]

Answer (score 3):

I'm biased, but I would start with these Visual Studio project templates...

https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=Chris-Hammond.DotNetNukeDNNDevelopmentProjectTemplates

You can follow this tutorial:
http://www.christoc.com/Tutorials/All-Tutorials/aid/2

The basics are (assuming you have your site running at dnndev.me, if not read this http://www.christoc.com/Tutorials/All-Tutorials/aid/1)

1. Load Visual Studio
2. Search for Online Templates "DotNetNuke"
3. Install the templates
4. Create a new Project, go to the DotNetNuke folder under C# or VB
5. Choose the project template for what type of project you want to create (Module, Theme)
6. Be sure to put the project in c:\websites\dnndev.me\desktopmodules\ (assuming you have your local dev site running at dnndev.me)

You can create it all yourself, but why? I've spent 14 years with DNN and those templates are a result of that, by far the easiest way to DNN

Comment: Thanks a lot for ur time sir, it is an honor, but i'm using webmatrix instead of iis and I just copied and pasted the content into ~\Documents\My Web Sites\DNN Platform®\DesktopModules and it compiles without error now, but the localhost is getting 403.14 - Forbidden error now :( , what should I do?

Comment: I'm not 100% sure how to check it in WebMatrix, but you'll want to confirm that the DesktopModules folder and the sub folders are not "APPLICATIONS". In IIS you would open IIS, and expand the sites node, expand the website, then look at the DesktopModules folder, does it look "different" from the others?